# How to modify and then inverse complex data that went through FFT algorithm?

Tags: rust, signal-processing, fft, lowpass-filter

I wrote a low-pass filter based around the FFT algorithm.

First I process the input data using forward FFT, then I decrease the "volume" of parts of the resulting spectrum, then I put the data into the inverse FFT and finally I normalize the data like this:

```rs
fn lowpass_filter(data: &[f32], sampling_rate: f32, cutoff_frequency: f32) -> Vec<f32> {
    let len = data.len();

    // step 1:
    let mut spectrum = fft::forward(&data);

    // step 2:
    let start: usize = (len as f32 * (cutoff_frequency / sampling_rate * 2.0)) as usize;
    let diff = len - start;

    // what to add to multiplikator in each iteration
    let step: f32 = PI / diff as f32;

    // reduce volume of frequencies after cutoff_frequency in spectrum
    let mut multiplikator: f32 = 0.0;
    for i in start..len {
        let mul = (multiplikator.cos() + 1.0) / 2.0;
        spectrum[i] *= mul;
        multiplikator += step;
     }

    // step 3:
    let data = fft::inverse(&spectrum);

    // step 4:
    fft::normalize(&data, true)
}
```

When only doing step 1, 3 and 4 it works but the only problem there is that after normalization of the inversed data, I only get the absolute value of the data back so a 65Hz sinus wave looks like this:[image: 65-Hz]

The main problem I am facing tho, is that I do not know how to reduce the volume of specific frequencies in the spectrum.

When reducing said frequencies like in step 3 the visualization of a 65Hz sinus wave put through that lowpass filter with the `cutoff_frequency` set to `100.0Hz` looks like this:
[image: 65-Hz-lowpass]

What did I do wrong here?

### More info about the defined functions:

```rs
use rustfft::FftPlanner;
pub use rustfft::num_complex::Complex;

pub fn forward(data: &[f32]) -> Vec<Complex<f32>> {
    let length = data.len();

    // conversion to complex numbers
    let mut buffer: Vec<Complex<f32>> = Vec::new();
    for d in data {
        buffer.push(Complex{re: *d, im: 0.0});
    }

    // creates a planner
    let mut planner = FftPlanner::<f32>::new();

    // creates a FFT
    let fft = planner.plan_fft_forward(length);

    //input.append(&mut data.to_vec());

    fft.process(&mut buffer);

    buffer
}

pub fn inverse(data: &[Complex<f32>]) -> Vec<Complex<f32>> {
    let length = data.len();

    let mut  data = data.to_vec();

    // creates a planner
    let mut planner = FftPlanner::<f32>::new();

    // creates a FFT
    let fft = planner.plan_fft_inverse(length);


    fft.process(&mut data);

    data.to_vec()
}

pub fn normalize(data: &[Complex<f32>], normalize: bool) -> Vec<f32> {
    let len: f32 = data.len() as f32;
    let norm = data
        .iter()
        .map(|x| x.norm() / len)
        .collect();

    norm
}
```

I am using [rustfft](https://github.com/ejmahler/RustFFT) for the actual processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Since you want to process real data (i.e. data whose imaginary part is `0`), the output of the forward FFT is symmetrical and you need to apply the same coefficient to matching frequencies (i.e. `spectrum[i]` and `spectrum[spectrum.len() - i]`, remembering that `spectrum[0]` stands alone, and so does `spectrum[spectrum.len()/2]` if the length is even).
2. If the frequencies are symmetrical, the result of the inverse FFT should be real (i.e. the imaginary part should be `0` ± small rounding errors). Therefore your `normalize` function should use `x.re` instead of `x.norm()`, which will allow it to retain its sign.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing these issues and adding a `cutoff_end_freq` to the `lowpass_filter` function the code looks like this:

```rs
pub fn lowpass_filter(data: &[f32], sampling_rate: f32, cutoff_start_freq: f32, cutoff_end_freq: f32) -> Vec<f32> {
    let len = data.len();
    let spectrum_len = len / 2;

    let mut spectrum = fft::forward(&data);
    assert!(len == spectrum.len());

    let start: usize = (spectrum_len as f32 * (cutoff_start_freq / sampling_rate * 2.0)) as usize;
    let end: usize = (spectrum_len as f32 * (cutoff_end_freq / sampling_rate * 2.0)) as usize;
    let diff = end - start;

    // what to add to multiplikator in each iteration
    let step: f32 = PI / diff as f32;

    let mut multiplikator: f32 = 0.0;
    for i in start..=end {
        let mul = (multiplikator.cos() + 1.0) / 2.0;
        spectrum[i] *= mul;
        spectrum[len - i - 1] *= mul;

        multiplikator += step;
    }
    for i in end..spectrum_len {
        spectrum[i] *= 0.0;
        spectrum[len - i - 1] *= 0.0;
    }

    let data = fft::inverse(&spectrum);

    fft::get_real(&data)
}
```

The `normalize` function now renamed to `get_real`:

```rs
pub fn get_real(data: &[Complex<f32>]) -> Vec<f32> {
    let len: f32 = data.len() as f32;
    let norm = data
        .iter()
        .map(|x| x.re / len)
        .collect();

    norm
}
```

Now it works very well, but there are still alternating "spikes" on each end when visualizing a frequency outside of the threshold:
[image: spikes]

I simply put a Hanning windowing effect over it because I heard that the FFT expects the data to be continuous.
And it works, with the drawback that a lot of information on the sides get lost.

Are there better methods to circumvent this problem or is there still something wrong with the lowpass?

Comment: There's still something wrong with the low-pass, but that's no longer a programming issue so probably not suited to StackOverflow. In a nutshell, the issue is that the FFT assumes that the signal is infinitely repeating, meaning that samples near each end of the signal affect the samples at the other end. I suggest googling "overlap-add" and "overlap-save" for more complete explanations and solutions.